# Why two ajax request is called with following JS code?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, long-polling

I have following code to pull data from server. I want to call it on document.ready(). And I expect first request is made to server, get response and second request is made and so on.

But I see in Firebug, there are two request to server is being made at initial page load. I am not sure why two request.
Here is my code.

```
;var EVENTS = {};
;(function($) {
EVENTS.Collector = {
events: [],
getEventsData: function() {
    var postData = {
        'jsonrpc': '2.0',
        'id': RPC.callid(),
        'method': "events.getNewOrUpdated",
        'params': {},
        'auth': RPC.auth()
    };
    var events_request = $.ajax({
        url: RPC.rpcurl(),
        contentType: 'application/json-rpc',
        type: "POST",
        data: JSON.stringify(postData),
        timeout: 30000
    });

    events_request.done(function(results) {
        //console.log("Info " + results);

        if (results.result.result !== null) {
            if (EVENTS.Collector.events.length !== 0) {
                alert(EVENTS.Collector.events.length);
            } else {
                alert(EVENTS.Collector.events.length);
            }
        }
    });

    events_request.fail(function(results) {
        //console.error("Error " + results);
        $("Error Message").insertAfter('.error');
    });

    events_request.always($.proxy(this.getEventsData, this));
} 
};

})(jQuery);

EVENTS.Collector.getEventsData(); //function call
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have a working example? A fiddle or plunker? Also, did you try setting debug point? That will show where the call is invoked from..

Comment: Is it intended to call getEventsData after all requests?

Comment: @Alphonso I am already using above code in my project, Ah..I sorry to mention that I have already tried with Firebug but can not get the answer.

Comment: @Mihir getEventsData is intended to be called on document.ready()

Comment: In your code it is executing after all ajax requests through `events_request.always($.proxy(this.getEventsData, this));` You can try comment that line.

Comment: @Mihir, If I comment out that line, then no additional request will be made to server again. I have code it so that it meets what we call "Long-polling".

Answer (score 0):

If you remove the code below does it call at all?

```
EVENTS.Collector.getEventsData(); //function call
```

Comment: No, after removing, no any ajax request is called. Can you explain why you think to remove?

Answer (score 0):

By default ajax request are *asynchronous*. If you want each request to be kind of "blocking" until done, then proceed to next, you can send sync request just by adding `async: false` to ajax call parameters.

Give a try to the following snippet, if it's what you meant to do..??.

```
var events_request = $.ajax({
    url: RPC.rpcurl(),
    contentType: 'application/json-rpc',
    type: "POST",
    async: false,
    data: JSON.stringify(postData),
    timeout: 30000
});
```

Consider that sync requests causes the interpreter function pointer to wait till any result come back from the call, or till request timeout.

Comment: your code is working with blocking mode, so only the same ajax(above) request is called every time. But I also have others ajax from another JS files, which are totally not being called when I set "async: false," in above ajax setting.